# Paper.js `getImageData/putImageData` with alpha channel

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I'm using Paper.js canvas as a source and a simple canvas as a target. Basically copying a part of the visible image via `getImageData` and pasting it into the target canvas with `putImageData`.

The pasted image does not have the alpha channel. For example when the copied area includes just a part of an object and the rest should be empty. I tried adding `{ colorSpace: 'display-p3' }` for both functions, but I see that the color space stays `srgb` and still no alpha channel.

Is it possible to copy/paste the image data with `getImageData` preserving the alpha channel with Paper.js?

Here's the copy/paste code.

```js
const rasterTemp = RasterObject.rasterize() // This to reset all the transformations.

const subRasterTemp = rasterTemp.getSubRaster(new data.$paper.Rectangle({
  point: [0, 0], // These and other coordinates are just for the sake of demonstration
  size: [100, 100],
}))

const imageData = subRasterTemp.getImageData(new data.$paper.Rectangle({
  point: [0, 0],
  size: [100, 100],
}), { colorSpace: 'display-p3' })

canvasTargetContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't really explain the reason why this works, but a workaround for this can be to first draw the image data on a temporary canvas and then draw this temporary canvas on your target canvas. I got the idea from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72297938/7615922).

And here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/gy67sx14/1/) demonstrating a possible solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Debug Paper.js</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/acorn"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
    }

    main {
      display: flex;
      gap: 10px;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    canvas {
      border: 1px solid;
    }

    p {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<main>
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
    <p>paper.js canvas</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <canvas id="target" resize></canvas>
    <p>target canvas</p>
  </div>
</main>

<script>
  // Setup Paper.js
  paper.setup('canvas');

  // Create a circle.
  const circle = new paper.Path.Circle({
    center: paper.view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange',
  });

  // Rasterize the drawing.
  const raster = paper.project.activeLayer.rasterize();
  // Get the image data from this raster.
  const imageData = raster.getImageData();

  // Get the target canvas.
  const targetCanvas = document.getElementById('target');
  const context = targetCanvas.getContext('2d');
  // Draw a black rectangle on it so that we can see the transparency.
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 50);
  putImageDataWithAlpha(targetCanvas, imageData);

  function putImageDataWithAlpha(canvas, imageData) {
    // Create a temporary canvas to draw the image data on it.
    const tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // Make it the same size as the given canvas.
    tmpCanvas.width = canvas.width;
    tmpCanvas.height = canvas.height;
    const tmpContext = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
    // Draw the image data on it.
    tmpContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    // Then draw this temporary canvas on the given canvas.
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(tmpCanvas, 0, 0);
    // Remove the temporary element.
    tmpCanvas.remove();
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've just found out that it actually uses the alpha channel. I got an impression that it doesn't because it redraws the opaque pixels with the transparent ones. I understand that it's kind of obvious if I'm literally putting the image data to the area, but it wasn't clear for me earlier. I simply saved the resulting image and saw the transparency. But thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's not actually the case. Transparency is being preserved. I just visually got an impression that it wasn't. But when I simply saved the canvas as an image I saw the transparency.